# Calculate the ticks of an axis for a chart with a stepsize

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, math

I've calculated a stepsize for an axis on a chart.

Also I have the Min and Max -Values. Now I need to calculate all ticks so that all values between my Min and Max can be displayed.

For Example:

Stepsize: 1000

Min: 213

Max: 4405

Expected ticks: 0,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000

---

Stepsize: 500

Min: -1213

Max: 1405

Expected ticks: -1500,-1000,-500,0,500,1000,1500

Until now I'm trying to calculate the first value with "try and error" like:

```cs
bool firstStepSet = false;
double firstStep = stepSize;
do
{
    if (xValue >= (firstStep - (stepSize / 2)) && xValue <= 
    (firstStep + (stepSize / 2)))
    {
        firstStepSet = true;
        this.myBarXValues.Add(firstStep, 0);
    }
    else if (xValue > stepSize)
    {
        firstStep += stepSize;
    }
    else
    {
        firstStep -= stepSize;
    }
}
while (!firstStepSet);
```

And after that I'm adding steps to this list until all values fit.

This seems pretty dirty to me and I want to know if there is another solution.

So what I need is a solution which calculate the first tick that I need.

Comment: Are you talking about MSChart or something you write from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function calculates first and last step values:

```
static void CalcSteps(int min, int max, int stepSize, out int firstStep, out int lastStep)
{
    if (min >= 0)
    {
        firstStep = (min / stepSize) * stepSize;
    }
    else
    {
        firstStep = ((min - stepSize + 1) / stepSize) * stepSize;
    }

    if (max >= 0)
    {
        lastStep = ((max + stepSize - 1) / stepSize) * stepSize;
    }
    else
    {
        lastStep = (max / stepSize) * stepSize;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate axis limits using integer rounding to lower and higher values

```
low = stepsize * (min / stepsize)  //integer division needed
high = stepsize * ((max + stepsize - 1) / stepsize)
```

Example Python code returns limits and number of ticks (one more than interval count)

```
def getminmax(minn, maxx, step):
    low = (minn // step)
    high = (maxx + step - 1) // step
    ticks = high - low + 1
    return low * step, high * step, ticks


print(getminmax(213, 4405, 1000))
print(getminmax(-1213,1405, 500))

(0, 5000, 6)
(-1500, 1500, 7)
```

Comment: doesn't work for negative in my case. Example: (int)(-2600/5000) results in 0

Comment: @Daniel Rose Because `int` in CSharp works as rounding to zero, not to `-infinity` (different languages use distinct rules)